# How to edit EXIF, IPTC and XMP metadata in cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, osx-snow-leopard

I want to read and edit EXIF, IPTC and XMP metadata of an images using cocoa.

I can read the EXIF metadata using

```
NSBitmapImageRep * imageTest = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithContentsOfFile:filePath] ;
  NSLog(@"Exif Data in %@ : %@",fileName, [imageTest valueForProperty:@"NSImageEXIFData"]) ;
```

How can I modify this data?

Thanks
Saurabh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [CGImageSource](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageSource/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001399) to read it in and [CGImageDestination](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageDestination/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001400) to write it back out.